# Scan large 10gb of Amazon DynamoDB data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, large-data

The following code works for me but it takes 19 minutes for 1 API request to return a result. An optimized result would be appreciated. I would not like to go for segments because then I will have to do thread management.

```html
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")

table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')

fe = Key('year').between(1950, 1959)
pe = "#yr, title, info.rating"
# Expression Attribute Names for Projection Expression only.
ean = { "#yr": "year", }
esk = None


response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=fe,
    ProjectionExpression=pe,
    ExpressionAttributeNames=ean
    )

for i in response['Items']:
    print(json.dumps(i, cls=DecimalEncoder))

// As long as LastEvaluatedKey is in response it means there are still items from the query related to the data
while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(
        ProjectionExpression=pe,
        FilterExpression=fe,
        ExpressionAttributeNames= ean,
        ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey']
        )

    for i in response['Items']:
        print(json.dumps(i, cls=DecimalEncoder))
```

Comment: what are the keys in your DynamoDb table? if your use case will generally be searching by year, consider using the year as some kind of key

Answer (score 1):

Because it is searching across all partitions, the `scan` operation can be very slow.  You wont be able to "tune" this query like you might if you were working with a relational database.

In order to best help you, I will need to know more about your access pattern (get movies by year?) and what your table currently looks like (what are your partition keys/sort keys, other attributes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `scan` is slow by nature. There is no way to optimize at the code level except for redesigning the table to optimize for this access pattern.